# How can I get a linked-list to hold both String and List objects?

Tags: dart, linked-list

So I am having trouble understanding what the issue is here. I am trying to create a linked-list that can hold a String and a List object. This is what I have so far:

```
import 'dart:collection';


void main() {
  var entry = LinkedList<MyLinkedListEntry<String,List>>();
  var list1 = List();

  entry.addFirst('First', list1);

}


class MyLinkedListEntry<T,U> extends LinkedListEntry< MyLinkedListEntry<T,U>>{
  T date;
  U array;
  MyLinkedListEntry(this.date,this.array);


}
```

The problem I am having is that I keep getting an error saying I have too many positional arguments or the argument type ‘String’ can’t be assigned to the parameter type 'MyLinkedListEntry'.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a linked list where the primary type is `MyLinkedListEntry`. That means you can only add items of that type to the list (or types that are convertible to it):

```dart
void main() {
  var entry = LinkedList<MyLinkedListEntry<String,List>>();
  var list1 = List();

  entry.addFirst(MyLinkedListEntry('First', list1));
}
```